# How to set value for antInclude attribute from exchange property in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am adding a property to exchange at runtime from the request.

```
exchange.setProperty("filePattern", String.format("*%s*", routeConfig.getFilePattern()))
```

Later, I am trying use the property for antInclude attribute as below

```
file:source?readLock=changed&antInclude=${exchangeProperty.filePattern}
```

Above code is not working, route created as below during runtime in log

```
 file://source?antInclude=%24%7BexchangeProperty.filePattern%7D&readLock=changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I see what you are trying to do here. Simple expressions won't work that way with a Polling Consumer like [File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html).

If you are using Camel 2.16+, you can use [pollEnrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) to get a behavior that you are trying to get here. It would be something like

```
from("direct:inputFileRoute")
                .pollEnrich("file:src/data?noop=true&antInclude=${exchange.filePattern}")
                .log("File Pattern is: ${exchangeProperty.filePattern}");
```

On a sidenote, are you sure you have to tweak the `antiInclude` option on the `File` component for every exchange? It looks like an overkill but I am unable to make a judgement based on the very limited input available here.  Perhaps what you are looking for is [Camel Properties](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html)